# Images not sized properly?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

I have a code that takes two JLabel images that are in grid layout, and put them next two eachother in a 2x2 layout. This is working, but it shows up in a really weird way. The images and all are all at the very bottom right and I can only see a tiny glimpse of blue (which is part of the color of one of my pictures). I don't know if this is a problem with my eclipse, or a problem with my code, but once I re-click the title bar of the window, it fixes itself up again and becomes how I want it to. How can I fix this, because I am pretty sure it is a problem in eclipse. I have provided the part of code that actually makes it:

```
    public class giraffe implements ActionListener{


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {


            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Press ok, and see the amazing giraffe outside a window!");

            JDialog giraffewindow = new JDialog();
            Icon giraffe = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("giraffe.png"));
            Icon windows = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("windows.png"));

            giraffewindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 0, 0));
            giraffewindow.add(new JLabel (windows));
            giraffewindow.add(new JLabel (giraffe));
            giraffewindow.setSize(2000,2000);
            giraffewindow.setTitle("GIRAFFE!");
            giraffewindow.setVisible(true);
            giraffewindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);



        }

    }
```

Again, I am 99% sure this is not a problem with code, but is a problem with my eclipse. What should I do to fix this? Thank you so much for the time you are taking for reading this, I really appreciate the effort you are putting into helping a fellow programmer!

Comment: Don't use the setSize() method. Use the `pack()` method and the dialog will size itself based on the size of the images.

Comment: Thank's a lot, I appreciate your answer. Do you mind telling me what I would do if I wanted to **proportionally** change the size of the dialog  while changing the size of the pictures? Thanks, Rich.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the setSize() method. 2000 x 2000 is probably larger than the size of your screen which is causing the problems.

Use the pack() method and the dialog will size itself based on the size of the images.

> if I wanted to proportionally change the size of the dialog while changing the size of the pictures?

Maybe you can use Darryl's [Stretch Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/) which will dynamically resize the image based on the space available.